# finding (local) maximum of a custom function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following function:

```
function res = score(probability)
```

where `probability = [.7 .4 .8 .1]` and `res = 0.8512` for example/

My goal is to find the probability vector (in 0.01 jumps) that maximizes `score`?
is there a matlab way for this? or should I loop for x times junping each time 0.01 in each probability above?

Comment: Your question is quite vague. How can you have 0.01 jumps if probability is a vector. How does that work? How does `res` follow from `probability` (what does score do)?  And do you have access to the optimization toolbox, i.e. did you try `fminsearch` or `fmincon` etc?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the vagueness, I meant doing 0.01 jumps for every vector index until you max them out to [1 1 1 1]. Res is a custom function,think of it as the Binomial distribution probability mass function. I haven't tried these tools, I am a novice at matlab.

Comment: It is still unclear. You change them all at the same time, or do you just have for independent parameters hidden in `probability`?

Comment: I mean change one index at a time, they are independent parameters of the distribution

Answer (score 0):

It depends on inner algorithm "score" function has.

However, if you want to use simple linear search kind of algorithm, you could have seed array of inputs and then vectorize on seeds to get maximum out of this.

For e.g.,

seed_ips=[0.1:0.01:0.14;
0.2:0.01:0.24];

results =array_fun(@(x) score(seed_ips(x)),1:size(seed_ips,1));

Now maximum value location will be "**find(results==max(results))**".

 Probability that produces max value will be **seed_ips(results==max(results),:)**

Comment: At least the `find` is not needed, because `max` already give the output that you are looking for in its second return value: i.e. `[maxValue, maxIndex] = max(results)`

Comment: Hmm. You are right. 
Never used second output from "max".

Answer (score 0):

I assume you whant to find a vector of probability for a max res with an accuracy of 0.01?

[this](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/optimizing-nonlinear-functions.html) is the way to go.
in your Case i migth look something like this:

```
score1   = @(prob) -score(prob)   % score here is your scorefunction
start    = [.7 .4 .8 .1]; % your start point 
opts     = optimset('TolX',0.01); % optim options
prob_vec = fminbnd(@score1,start,opts)
```

hope this helps,
have fun